# Testing a SmatContract on Ropsten - The transaction is "Success" but I didn't get token in my wallet

Tags: ether, metamask, javascript

I'm trying to take my first steps in the blockchain, and sometimes I stuck with some very weird issue (for me), this is one of them.

I've deployed a very simple SmallContract that inherit from `@openzeppelin/contracts@3.4.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol`, just to create a custom ERC20 token for testing.

This contract has a function named "mint()" that should return to my wallet 10 custom tokens.

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@3.4.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Token is ERC20 {

  constructor () ERC20("Issimissimo", "DS") {
    _setupDecimals(2);
    _mint(msg.sender, 10 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
  }

  function mint() public returns (bool) {
    _mint( msg.sender, 1000 );
    return true;
  }
}
```

I've deployed this contract on Ropsten, and I've tested in Unity (without Metamask, just using my private key) and it work, I receive the token in my wallet.

Now I'm trying do the same in JS, with "ethers" library, connecting to Metamask.
Well, I successfully connect to my Metamask account on Robsten, I successfully call the "mint" function, and I receive the message that the transaction is completed (I can also see on etherscan  that everyhing was fine --- Status: Success), but I didn't receive any custom token in my Metamask wallet...

How is possible? I guess that if I did some error in my JS code I would not receive the transaction confirmation message, and on Etherscan I should see some error... isn't it?
Maybe the Ropsten network can fail?

P.S. If can help this is the link of the transaction on etherscan
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xf7a2f2e112f7808431ab0e1ecf5e1dbd868a6ad21d205464660aed9920fddcea

Sorry but I'm very new to everything...

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your metamask wallet, change your network to 'Ropsten Network', then click on link called `Import tokens` and put into `Token Contract Address` textbox the address of your ERC20 smart contract in this case this value: `0x345fe1f0BbB9673b0844F6405FFC0e867d9591a1`.

[image]

After this operation, you can click on button called `Add Custom Token` and you'll see your tokens into your wallet.

Comment: Damn... you are totally right! I've changed a bit the function of the contract and I've deployed a new one a couple of days ago... so the token name is the same, but the contract address is changed, so I have to import the token again! Indeed now I can see in my wallet 2 tokens with the same name... Ok, this was my first thought when I've seen that every time you change the contract and you deploy it, it's address change. Is there a way to avoid this mess?